# is Haskell sensitive to order in a function definition?

Tags: haskell

I was trying out the Haskell 99 problems and my first attempt was this one .Although the solution may be a little incorrect ,I just want to know why Haskell throws a warning for the first one and outputs the wrong result

```
> let { mylast (x:xs) = mylast xs; mylast [] = 0 ;mylast [x] = x;}
Pattern match(es) are overlapped

> mylast [1,2,3,58,8,6,1,231,10]
> 0
```

but the code below executes just fine.

```
> let { mylast [] = 0 ;mylast [x] = x;mylast (x:xs) = mylast xs;}
> mylast [1,2,3,58,8,6,1,231,10]
> 10
```

Comment: BTW, returning `0` as a “failure default” is very un-Haskellish. You should probably make it `myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a`; `myLast [] = Nothing`; `myLast [x] = Just x`.

Comment: I'm just learning Haskell and I did not know how to return null. I just started looking at the maybe type .thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the patterns in a function definition are tried in the specified order, and (only) the first matching line is used.

So in your definition

```
mylast (x:xs) = mylast xs
mylast [] = 0
mylast [x] = x
```

(reformatted for clarity), a non-empty-list will always be handled by the first line, even the list `[x]` (with `x=x` and `xs=[]`). So your calculation of `mylast` will happily ignore *every* element in the list, and finally look at `[]`, hence returning `0`.

Answer (score 7):

...in other words, Haskell doesn't consider which of two matches is more general and then use the more specific one first. It just considers “does it match or doesn't it?”

In some cases it wouldn't be possible to say which of two matches is more specific. For instance,

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo 0 _ = 0
foo _ 1 = 1
foo n m = foo (m-1) n
```

If Haskell was supposed to pick the most specific matching pattern, then what result should `foo 0 1` yield?

You need to have some arbitrary tie-breaker for such functions, and in Haskell that's simply the order: *always match the upper clause first*.